# Unit testing dynamically created controls in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, unit-testing

I am using MVP pattern for a windows forms project and have left some of the creation logic in the view because I read that it shouldn't really be separated out from the form anyway. So now that I am coming to test the form I don't know how I can unit test methods like this. I have read about mocking but I'm not sure how to implement it with controls being created.

```
    internal void createExamLabels(List<string> examList)
    {
        labelList = new List<Label>();

        foreach (string exam in examList)
        {
            LinkLabel label = new LinkLabel();
            label.Text = exam;
            label.Location = labelPoint;
            label.Click += examlabelLinkClicked;
            label.AutoSize = true;
            this.Controls.Add(label);
            labelList.Add(label);
            labelPoint.Y = labelPoint.Y + 30;

        }
    }
```

or this

```
    private void Form_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        int count = 1;
        while (count == 1)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, rec);
            count++;
        }


            DrawCircle(e.Graphics, point.X, point.Y);

    }

    private void DrawCircle(Graphics g, float x, float y)
    {

        using (Brush semiTransBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Coral))
        {
            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Aquamarine, 2))
            {
                g.DrawEllipse(pen, x, y, 50, 50);
                g.FillEllipse(semiTransBrush, x, y, 50, 50);

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't.

As a general rule, unit tests should not touch an "outside" system such as the file system, a database, or the UI.

I have worked on an enterprise application which had "unit tests" for some WPF controls. Those tests were the most unstable, longest-running, and most difficult to troubleshoot tests in our entire unit test suite.

Focus your unit testing efforts on the parts of the application where it is a better fit. For the MVP pattern you cited, focus on the model and the presenter. Leave the UI testing for ad hoc testing.